# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null

Tags: android, imageview, fragment

I want to show my `ImageView` always on top. This `ImageView` is in the `Fragment`. 
But, I got an error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null
```

Here is my code.

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapview, container, false);
    mImageFloor = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_floor);


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, 
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);                                                          

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(mContext.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mImageFloor, params);  // *This line has an error
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a file called `fragment_mapview.xml`?  Also, are you returning `rootView` at the end of `onCreateView()`?

Comment: @DanielNugent Yeah. If I run this code without `WindowManager ...` something, It worked well.

Comment: @DanielNugent And No. I'm returning another View.